# findig duplicate elements in an array, not working

Tags: c

Hi friends i have this array and i am trying to find out how many elements are duplicate and what are the remaining elements. But the problem it is showing different result. Please check it

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 30

int const arr_1[SIZE] = {3,4,3,7,4,90,45,23,57,68,23,14,57,
                   34,20,39,18,3,2,23,45,67,89,68,12,34,56,78,3
                   };



int main()
{

  int i,j,yes=0, no=0;

  for(i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
  {
     for(j=0; j<SIZE; j++)
     {
        if(arr_1[i] == arr_1[j])

              yes++; 
         else 

           no++;   

     }

  }

  printf("temp: %d\t Not: %d\n",yes,no);

  system("PAUSE");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you expect to be result for `{3,3,3,3}`?

Comment: What are `temp` and `not`??

Comment: You should note that you also check every number against itself right now, you may want to add an exclusion for that :)

Answer (score 0):

What about your `temp` and `not` variables? Don't you use `yes` and `no`?

Actually algorythm have to be corrected:

```
for (i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
{
    int notfound = 0;
    for (j = i + 1; j < SIZE; j++)
    {
        if (arr_1[i] == arr_1[j])
        {
            yes++; 
            notfound = 1; //found, no need to iterate anymore
            break;
        }
    }
    if (notfound == 0) //and we know that element isn't duplicate only here
        no++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are comparing each pair of elements twice.  For example, you are comparing `arr_1[1] == arr_1[2]`, but later in your loop you also compare `arr_1[2] == arr_1[1]`, so the result counts twice.  In addition, you are comparing element `i` with element `i`, which will always be the same.  To fix this, you should change:

```
for(j=0; j<SIZE; j++)
```

to

```
for(j=i+1; j<SIZE; j++)
```

This way, the second loop starts from the current index of the first loop and you only check each pair once.

Answer (score 0):

```
 #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int arr_1[30] = {3,4,3,7,4,90,45,23,57,68,23,14,57,34,20,39,18,3,2,23,45,67,89};
    int main()
    {

      int i,j,yes=0;
      for(i=0;i<23;i++)
      {
      yes=0;

         for(j=0; j<23; j++)
         {
            if(i==j){continue;}
            if(arr_1[i] == arr_1[j])
                yes++; 


         }
         if(yes==0)
             { printf("\n%d unique element",arr_1[i]);
              }
         else
              { printf("\n%d repeat %d time(s) " ,arr_1[i],yes);}

      }



  return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: check this code it will display unique number and duplicate number. if you want to display duplicate number count itself. then initialize yes=1